# How to use alternatives container in Moveit2?

Tags: ros, ros2, moveit, moveit2

I want to have a better idea about using [alternatives container.](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/concepts/moveit_task_constructor/parallel_containers.html#parallel-containers) How can I use it with other containers such as MoveTo?